# How to print and save multiple ggplot graphs without using for-loops?

Tags: r, for-loop, graph, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with lots of possible combinations of variables and for exploratory purposes I need to see univariate distributions from these combinations of variables. I succeeded doing it with for loops but would like to find a better and a faster way of doing it. Anybody has an idea?

I have produced a following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
SubjectID <- c(3772113,3772468)
Group <- c("Easy","Hard")
Object <- c("A","B")
dat <- data.frame(expand.grid(SubjectID,Group,Object))
dat$RT <- rnorm(8,1500,700)
colnames(dat) <- c("SubjectID","Group","Object","RT")

# GGplot function
pl <- function(x,group, object){
  x <- filter(x, Group==group, Object==object)
  print(ggplot(x,aes(x=RT)) + 
          geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05) +
          xlab("Reactions per second") +
          ggtitle(paste(as.character(group),"_",as.character(object)), sep=""))
  ggsave(paste(as.character(group),"_",as.character(object),".png"), path = "...")
}

for (group in unique(dat$Group)){
  for (object in unique(dat$Object)){
    pl(dat,group,object)
  }
}
```

How can I replace the nested for loops in this graph printing?

Comment: edited your answer with `dat` instead of `sp`(otherwise not reproducible). Also, I think your `paste` line should finish with `,".png", sep="")` or `paste` be turned into `paste0` otherwise spaces are added in the filenames.

Comment: Faceting is not an option?

Comment: @Roland It was an option, but the quality was a bit bad (there are 11 objects in the "real" dataframe). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `lapply`:

```
all_comb <- with(dat, expand.grid(levels(Group), levels(Object)))
lapply(1:nrow(all_comb), 
       function(i) pl(dat, group = all_comb[i, 1], object=all_comb[i, 2]))
```

Comment: Tried and it works! Sadly it's not much quicker than for loops... Thank you!